# How to solder a 5.5x2.1 DC plug to a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I am looking at mounting a DC plug on the side of my PCB board.
Unfortunately, only jacks exists for purpose of PCB mounting, and there are no mountable plugs produced.
**(if they existed, they would look something like image below, which is a microphone jack, very rare item found on Alibaba)**
[image: microphone plug]

*Since the PCB will have custom 3D printed enclosure, I am considering using a normal jack and hiding a DC-DC coupler if there's no better solution for PCB assembly service.*
However, I am looking at a small form factor and every cm counts, so that's a downside.
[image: dc dc coupler]

What's a possible way to get a DC plug on a side of PCB, in a way that's accepted by popular PCB assembly services?
It should have a predictable position when mounted.

Image sources:
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/OEM-Mount-4-Pole-Earphone-Aux_1600250900700.html?spm=a2700.details.0.0.34b0756ekvX7K3
https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/1005004831917801.html

Comment: A quick search on mouser yields a bunch: https://eu.mouser.com/c/connectors/power-connectors/dc-power-connectors/?mounting%20style=Through%20Hole&product=Plugs&instock=y

Comment: @DamienD  only one goes to the side and it handles 0.5A. I need about 12V@2-3A.

Comment: actually, the rating was for a different similar plug below, and the correct one 173-5521TIP-EX has no power rating at all. I should contact Mouser, however if they say it's less than that - my project will be again stuck

Comment: are you able to estimate the power rating based on the image? will the plastic melt with 12V@3A?

Comment: can't say without knowing how it's made inside. But as an aside, this assembly will be mechanically fragile — the large lever arm means bending the connector will easily crack the PCB, unless it's very small compared to the plug.

Comment: there is one more part on the market hiding as a laptop adapter [here](https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/1005003919749553.html). as for bending, I can probably design the 3D printed case to stabilize it